# Sort huge list (130Gb) in Linux

Tags: sort

I'm trying to `sort` a huge list (130 Gb) in Linux. Partially like this:

```
@K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:27440:1668 1:N:0:0_I_CGATGT
@K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:30262:1668 1:N:0:0_I_CGATGT
@K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:6501:1686 1:N:0:0_I_CGATGT
@K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:18133:1686 1:N:0:0_I_CGATGT
@K00188:14:H2LMFBBXX:6:1101:21827:1686 1:N:0:0_I_CGATGT
```

The problem is the not enough RAM during `sort`.

There are some solutions from previous questions (e.g. `sort --parallel`, python scripts etc.) but they didn't work out on my hand.

I want to stick to `sort` but the following error message appeared while using the option `--parallel`

```
sort: unrecognized option '--parallel=2'
Try `sort --help' for more information.
```

If there are some python scripts written for sorting big lists, I would like to have a try.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system? What Linux distribution? Please **edit your question** to improve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sort` (except for some stripped-down implementations like `busybox`) is not limited by memory as it only uses a limited amount and resorts to temporary files when it reaches that limit.

More likely, you ran out of disk space. You'll need about 130GB of free disk space in the temporary area `sort` is using (in addition to the disk space used to store the result unless you write the file over itself with `sort -o mybigfile mybigfile`).

If there's not enough in the filesystem of `/tmp`, set `$TMPDIR` to a location with more free disk space (see also the `-T` option with some `sort` implementations):

```
TMPDIR=~/tmp sort my-big-file > sorted
```

To reduce the amount of temporary disk space needed, with some `sort` implementations, you can also tell it to compress the temporary files. That might even improve performance if you pick a compressor that is easy on CPU like `lzop` and have a file system on rotational disks.

```
TMPDIR=~/tmp sort --compress-program=lzop my-big-file > sorted
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to sort a huge list (130 Gb).

You want to sort a huge textual file line by line.

> sort: unrecognized option '--parallel=2'

It is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation) as an option accepted by recent GNU coreutils. So you are unlucky to not have the GNU corutils' `sort`  but some other one. So I would recommend compiling and installing a *recent* [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), e.g. coreutils-8.27 from its [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.27.tar.xz) (in summer 2017). You could use `--program-suffix=-my`  to its `configure` script to get `sort-my` installed (to avoid messing with the system provided `sort`).

<sup>(even without root privileges, you could `configure` with e.g. `--prefix=$HOME/pub` then `make install`; you may then want to add `$HOME/pub/bin/`  to your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))....)</sup>

If that is not possible, you could use [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)), then sort every smaller chunk, then merge them (using `sort --merge`).

Another possibility could be to write some tiny Python script parsing that huge file and putting it into some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database.

**I strongly recommend getting and using a recent GNU *coreutils*** (any other approach would take much more of your time). It is the most practical approach. You'll probably need enough extra free space on your filesystem (probably 150Gb) to run the sort.

If you never compiled any GNU utilities from their source, I recommend the following steps:

- get the coreutils source tar ball e.g. using `wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.27.tar.xz` or your browser.
- extract it using `tar xvf coreutils-8.27.tar.xz`  (with a recent GNU tar); otherwise uncompress it using `xz -d coreutils-8.27.tar.xz`  then extract it with `tar xvf coreutils-8.27.tar`
- make a directory for installing GNU utilities with `mkdir $HOME/gnu/`
- go into the coreutils source directory `cd coreutils-8.27`
- configure before compiling:

  ```
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/gnu/ --program-suffix=-my
  ```

If you got some error message, try to correct your system (e.g. because of missing utilities like the C compiler) and/or ask for help. Read about [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) and [configure scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) to understand the options.

- build it

  ```
  make
  ```
- install it (if the build went well)

  ```
  make install
  ```

(You don't need any root privilege to run all that above)

- then use `$HOME/gnu/bin/sort-my` to do the sort (you might consider adding `$HOME/gnu/bin/` to your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) to be able to simply type `sort-my`)